# How to maintain two binaries of same iOS app on App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have an iOS app with minimum deployment version 9.0. I want to support the same app for versions less than equal to 8.0, but with a different binary. So, is it possible to maintain different binaries based on version numbers?

Comment: You can release a new version that targets iOS 9+ and select the option to leave the old version available for users with older iOS versions, but all updates will only be for the new version.

Comment: Why not just update your current app with iOS 8 support? Even if you make different app, Apple might reject yours because its duplicate

Comment: @Paulw11 - I want the old version to have new updates as well. So, I am not able to figure out a solution for that.

Comment: @Tj3n - The iOS 9 version has a library which is not compatible with previous versions. So, I want to support previous versions with older versions of the library.

Comment: Then your choices are two apps (which Apple has rejected), make your one app adapt to the iOS version so that it can work on iOS 8 and later, or (and this would be my choice) ditch support for iOS earlier than 9 ([there’s not many users on iOS 8 or earlier](https://data.apteligent.com/ios/))

Answer (score 0):

You can do it With different App bundle identifier as a separate app.

Comment: I tried to upload the same app, with different bundle identifier as a separate app, but they rejected saying it's a duplicate.